# Walking: 60 mins, 2 sessions of 30 mins, or 3 sessions of 20 mins?

Tags: health, walking

I now work at home at a computer all day. I am trying to make sure I'm moving more now so I plan to start simple with brisk walking. What is better for over all health? One 60 minute walk in the morning, two 30 minute walks (e.g. morning and lunch break), or three 20 minute walks (e.g. every ~2.5 hours)?

I've heard you generally need to move for at least 20 minutes to get positive affects from exercise, but I've also heard that long duration of being seated isn't healthy.

Comment: This question is most likely answered by [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/44648/spreading-aerobic-activity), in particular noting that the World Health Organisation did away with minimum exercise durations in the 2020 update to their physical activity guidelines.

Comment: Ah okay. I was searching for if it had been previously asked but I didn't user those wonder and did not find anything. Thanks for finding this.